# Python Selenium Handle popup alert

Tags: python, selenium, alert

So I'm trying to make this program where I make it search for an anime on nyaa.si with filters and such, and i wanted to spice it up a little. Long story short, when I tap on the magnet button, it always asks me to prompt permission for qbittorrent to open the magnet link.[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj06e.png) Here's the code, but the important section is at the end of it and the error I get is this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Asus/Documents/Projects/python/selNyaaSi/main.py", line 49, in <module>
    driver.switch_to.alert().accept();
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 55, in alert   
    alert.text
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\alert.py", line 67, in text        
    return self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_GET_ALERT_TEXT)["value"]
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124) alert
```

code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import json
    from time import sleep
    from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert


headless = False

path = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
if input('headless?: ') != '':
    headless = True
    options.add_argument('headless')

with open('urls.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=options)
url = data['urls']['nyaa']
driver.get(url)

if headless == False:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'themeToggle'))).click()


driver.find_element_by_class_name('navbar-toggle.collapsed').click()

driver.find_elements_by_class_name('form-control')[0].send_keys('Bleach')

temp = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('select.form-control')
_filter = temp[0]
_category = temp[1]

_filter.click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select.form-control[title=Filter] option[title="Trusted only"]').click()


_category.click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select.form-control[title=Category] option[value="1_2"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-primary.form-control').click()

temp = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr.success td.text-center i.fa.fa-fw.fa-magnet')
temp[0].click()
driver.switch_to.alert().accept()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: added full traceback!

Answer (score 2):

I dont see anything about alerts in your code, only the import. You should have something like this after the magnet.click():

```
driver.switch_to.alert().accept(); # or dismiss() if you dont want to accept
```

Comment: I updated the code, now it shows your suggestion. But I still get the same error for some reason.